# Organizing and routing AJAX calls in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 and I have played with AJAX. I have successfully got it to work. The page that have Ajax links on it is the show.html.erb. It has a feed which have posts, and the posts has comments. To avoid loading everything I use Ajax for loading pieces of the post list and the comment list. Much like Facebook does.

I have organised it the following way: the pages controller checks if there is an `ajax_action` query parameter present. If it does it renders the JavaScript-response. It checks with a `before_action`. The value of the `ajax_action` are `load_posts`, `load_comments` and `load_replies`. They map to private methods in the pages controller.

Does this sound like a good approach when I need different Ajax methods on the same page? Or do you do it another way?

code from the pages controller:

```
    before_action :delegate_ajax, only: :show

    def delegate_ajax
        ajax_action = params[:ajax_action]
        unless ajax_action.nil?
          ajax_handlers = {'load_posts' => 'load_posts', 'load_comments' => 'load_comments'}
          send(ajax_handlers[ajax_action])
        end
      end

def load_posts
    # Some logic (hidden for now)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'load_posts', layout: false }
    end
  end

def load_comments
    # Some logic (hidden for now)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'load_comments', layout: false }
    end
  end
```

At least doing it like this keeps the routes.rb oblivious to all the AJAX routes.

Comment: I'd consider this from the perspective of a developer inheriting this code. Why not just load the posts from the posts controller as convention dictates? What's the advantage in keeping the routes file oblivious to AJAX routes?